# How to take data from a .txt list and save the result in another .txt?

Tags: hashlib

I don’t know the Python language, but I need to change this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Addresses

import hashlib
import base58

# ECDSA bitcoin Public Key
pubkey = '02e026fdf8f48819c1d6a3711cd547d82cc9de5d5fed05316cdaeddddd503cf233'
# See 'compressed form' at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Signatures
compress_pubkey = False


def hash160(hex_str):
    sha = hashlib.sha256()
    rip = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    sha.update(hex_str)
    rip.update( sha.digest() )
    return rip.hexdigest()  # .hexdigest() is hex ASCII


if (compress_pubkey):
    if (ord(bytearray.fromhex(pubkey[-2:])) % 2 == 0):
        pubkey_compressed = '02'
    else:
        pubkey_compressed = '03'
    pubkey_compressed += pubkey[2:66]
    hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_compressed)
else:
    hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey)

# Obtain key:

key_hash = '00' + hash160(hex_str)

# Obtain signature:

sha = hashlib.sha256()
sha.update( bytearray.fromhex(key_hash) )
checksum = sha.digest()
sha = hashlib.sha256()
sha.update(checksum)
checksum = sha.hexdigest()[0:8]

print ( "" + (base58.b58encode( bytes(bytearray.fromhex(key_hash + checksum)) )).decode('utf-8') )
```

Here need to take the public key data from the file list: **Pubkey.txt**
and save the processed data to a new file: **Results.txt**
Earlier, I saw scenarios in which data are taken from one text document, perform a function, and the result is stored in another text document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As this isn't a coding service site, I would recommend you to change the scope of your question and try yourself. If you have problems, you can come here again. You may also want to take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you don’t need to import a library in order to read and write files in python:

```py
#reading
file = open("Pubkey.txt","r") 
file.read()
file.close()

#writing
file = open("Results.txt","w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

Comment: How to write it in code? I understand the language very poorly. Help fix the code?